# Porque no puedo declarar métodos static en una interfaz en java?

Tags: java, poo, interfaz

tengo una duda, porque no puedo declarar un método static en una interfaz en java?
Intento declarar el método desde una interfaz pero me sale el siguiente error "falta cuerpo del método, o declararlo abstract"

```
public interface Test {
    public static int test1();
}
```

También intenté de esta forma pero me sale que debo añadir un return cuando solamente he declarado el metodo.

```
public interface Test {
    public static int test1(){}
}
```

Porque pasa esto y como podría solucionarlo? estoy usando NetBeans 8.0.2

Comment: Los métodos estáticos son métodos que pertenecen a la clase, no a la instancia. Cuando los declaras en una interfaz, estos pertenecen a dicha interfaz y deben estar implementados. Esto es así porque en java los métodos y variables marcados como static deben llamarse siempre desde la clase que los contiene... si lo intentas hacer static abstract, cómo vas a llamarlo desde la clase si estás indicando que lo vas a implementar en la subclase?? Por cierto que en el momento en que pones los corchetes estás definiendo la implementación del método, ergo debe tener un return del tipo adecuado.

Comment: para que querrias un metodo estatico?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventualmente crearás una clase (o varias) que implemente esta interfaz. Esa clase debe implementar tooodos los métodos de tu interfaz usando la anotación `@Override`.

Sin embargo, desde Java 8 también puedes añadir métodos estáticos en tu interfaz porque organizacionalmente son de la interfaz (digamos, clase `Figura`) y no de las clases que la implementan (ej `Cuadrado`, `Circulo`, etc).

Peeeeero:

- implementar la interfaz no significa que heredas alli el método estático; y
- el método estático se invoca sin instanciar la clase donde se define (y, además, no instancias nunca una interfaz directamente).

Así que debes ponerle un cuerpo al método estático en la interfaz para poder cumplir con la forma como invocas un método estático, `Test.test1()` y que realmente haga algo.

PD. Si en una declaración de un método pones `{}`, inmediatamente el dios compilador te va a castigar porque eso implica que hay un cuerpo del método sin retornar el tipo de dato esperado.